# Change File ext with GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

One of the sites i visit has an annoying habit of naming all their files showimage.php. When i save the image or file it saves as a .php so i cannot open the file. The worse part is, there is a &ext=zip&more=blah in the url.

Is it possible to use greasemonkey to rename the file ext so it isnt php? (maybe injecting a content disposition header?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I couldn't figure it out with GreaseMonkey but if you're willing to use another plugin then DownThemAll is what you need: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201

Comment: hmm, i cant save it as fast as a normal right click + v + enter but its not much longer and WAY better then renaming the files

Comment: DownThemAll is pretty full blast (whatever that means) and maybe you can get it to do what you initially wanted and with the same efficiency.